# How to add box and label to pie graph exactly as shown in figure below

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to create a graph exactly like in figure below and want to save it as jpeg.
I have a dataframe named 'custpref' as below

```
tov_type            count
Inpatient               7
Office Visit            6
Appointment Schedule    1
Allergy Sheet           1
```

Tried Code is as follows:-

```
def addPieGraph():
# Create a list of colors (from iWantHue)
colors = ["#6287da","#72ac5c","#8653aa","#bb7438","#b94b75"]

# Create a pie chart
plt.pie(
    # using data total)arrests
    custpref['cnt'],
    # with the labels being officer names
    labels=custpref['tov_type'],
    # with no shadows
    shadow=False,
    # with colors
    colors=colors,
    # with the start angle at 90%
    startangle=90,
)

# View the plot drop above
plt.axis('equal')

# View the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title("Top 5 Visit Types                  Total = 15 Visits")
plt.savefig(r"PieChart.png",bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

expected result:-
[expected look of pie graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdslw.png)

The code above plots the pie graph just need help with the legends,arrows pointing to them, the count in front of names and label in rectangular box with border around the graph as in expected output.

(legands from above dataframe and expected graph may vary as it changes for each graph. I am expecting just exact look for my graph as shown in expected image.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* While it's not a perfect recreation of your goal, I think it's close enough for you to fine-tune to your desired result.

I've used `gridspec` to create two separate subplots (`pie_chart` and `title`), added custom annotation lines (adapted [from the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html)), and formatted the `title` subplot to black, without any visible ticks/spines.

**Plot result:**

[image]

**Complete code used:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

custpref=pd.DataFrame({'tov_type':['Inpatient','Office Visit','Appointment Schedule','Allergy Sheet'],'count':[7,6,1,1]})

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1,
    left=0.1,right=0.7,
    bottom=0.1,top=0.7,
)
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1,
    left=0.05,right=0.95,
    bottom=0.9,top=1.0,
)

pie_ax=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0])
title_ax=fig.add_subplot(gs2[0])

# Create a list of colors (from iWantHue)
colors = ["#6287da","#72ac5c","#8653aa","#bb7438","#b94b75"]

# Create a pie chart
wedges, texts = pie_ax.pie(
    # using data total)arrests
    custpref['count'],
    # with no shadows
    shadow=False,
    # with colors
    colors=colors,
    # with the start angle at 90%
    startangle=90,
)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle,"color":colors[i]})
    pie_ax.annotate(custpref['tov_type'][i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                 horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

# View the plot drop above
pie_ax.axis('equal')


title_ax.set_facecolor('k')

title_ax.text(0.5,0.5,"Top 5 Visit Types                  Total = 15 Visits",
    ha="center",va="center",transform=title_ax.transAxes,color="w")

for side in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    title_ax.spines[side].set_visible(False)
title_ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)    
title_ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)    


plt.savefig(r"PieChart.png",bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This worked for me but in some cases I am getting error "Given lines do not intersect. Please verify that the angles are not equal or differ by 180 degrees." Any solution for it?

Comment: @P.Natu Hmm, that seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12820) in matplotlib 3.x due to the use of `tight_layout()`; if you `import matplotlib`, what's your `print(matplotllib.__version__)`?

Comment: its 3.0.3. I also tried with different start angles. Setting startangle = -40 works in this case. Will it work in other such cases? ..